# Django authentication login() returns anonymous user

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, authentication, django-2.x

I am trying to log in to a database that is not the default database, and for that I've wrote a custom authentication code but whenever I try to login the method returns an `AnonymousUser`. I've no idea why is it doing so because user authentication is done properly using the `authenticate` method.

Any help would be really appreciated.

**MY FILES**

***views.py***

```py
def login_authentication(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = New_Login_Form(request.POST)
        # print(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            email = request.POST['email']
            password = request.POST['password']
            user_operating_company = request.POST['user_operating_company']
            user = authenticate(request, email=email,
                                password=password, db=user_operating_company)
            if user:
                login(request, user, user_operating_company)
                return redirect('test')
    else:
        form = New_Login_Form()
        return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})
```

***backends.py***

```py
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
from .models import Account

class CustomAuthenticate(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, email=None, password=None, db=None):
        try:
            user = Account.objects.all().using(db).get(email=email)
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        except:
            return None

    def get_user(self, request, email, db):
        try:
            return Account.objects.using(db).get(pk=email)
        except:
            return None
```

and in the

***settings.py***

```py
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('accounts.backends.CustomAuthenticate', 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend')
```

**EDIT:**

I made the changes as per @schillingt 's answer the updated backend is:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
from .models import Account

class CustomAuthenticate(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, email=None, password=None, db=None):
        self.db = db
        try:
            user = Account.objects.using(db).get(email=email)
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        except Account.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def get_user(self, email):
        try:
            user =  Account.objects.using(self.db).get(pk=email)
        except Account.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        return user if self.user_can_authenticate(user) else None
```

But now it gives me an error which says

```py
'CustomAuthenticate' object has no attribute 'db'
```

Comment: I would recommend checking up on the [Multuple databases setion](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/multi-db/) at the Django Docs. Also, are you sure the user is also *created* in the separate database?

Comment: Yes I'm sure, as I've manually created it in a seperate database.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have the wrong signature for `get_user`. ModelBackend's is:

```
def get_user(self, user_id):
    try:
        user = UserModel._default_manager.get(pk=user_id)
    except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
        return None
    return user if self.user_can_authenticate(user) else None
```

This method is used by `django.contrib.auth.get_user`. Does your backend have a reference to the `db` instance that should be used? Or is that defined on the request? If it's defined on the request, you may have to monkey patch the `django.contrib.auth.get_user` method to supply the proper parameters to the call to the backend's `get_user` method so that you have the right `db` instance.

Edit:

[This](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend) makes it seem like I'm wrong. You shouldn't have to monkey patch `django.contrib.auth.get_user`. You should be able to set the db instance on the backend instance in `authenticate`, then utilize that in `get_user`.

Comment: The database does have the reference to the `db` instance, and could you please explain the monkey patch approach or atleast provide some resources for it.

Comment: Do you mean the backend has the reference to the db instance?

Comment: See edit. The monkey patching shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Can you please check the program in the edit section it is giving an error as mentioned.

Comment: Can you verify that when authenticate is called that `db` is not None?

Comment: Yes I've verified it as the `authenticate` works properly and returns the user object

Comment: Did you verify that `db is not None`?

Comment: Yes, I did verify it

Comment: Sorry, we're beyond what I can help you without taking a deep dive into your code.

Comment: Thanks for the help, if you find any answer please do share it.